# is ambiguity of DCFL(deterministic context free language) UNDECIDABLE?

Tags: computation-theory

[image]

[image: strong text]

///////////////////////////////////////

As DCFL name itself suggests that there is determinism at each stage of input hence no possibility of a choice..Hence every DCFL contains at least one unambiguous grammar.In fact the language for which there is no unambiguous grammar is known as inherently ambiguous..Inherent ambiguity begins from CFL layer of Chomsky hierarchy.

-Source https://gateoverflow.in/155464/dcfl-ambiguity

> so this article says that every dcfl is unambiguous . but table says that ambiguity for dcfl is undecidable  .... how????

////////////////////////////////////

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see which questions are on-topic on this site.
You might want to delete this question and ask it on https://cs.stackexchange.com/ instead, but check the help pages there first.

Answer (score 1):

Every language that is deterministic has at least one deterministic grammar. Every deterministic grammar is unambiguous.

I do not think that there is a formal definition of what an "ambiguous language" is. Strictly speaking, every non-empty language has more then one possible grammar (by just duplicating any rule in the grammar as much as desired will make it ambiguous), thus if it is defined that "a language that has at least one ambiguous grammar is ambiguous" then **all** non-empty languages would be ambiguous.

However, if there is no unambiguous grammar for a language then that is an **inherently ambiguous language**.

I think that if its already known that a language is deterministic then to decide "is the language ambiguous" boils down to deciding "is it empty or not". That is straight forward, because an empty language has **no** strings at all, even the empty string.

All that said, I think that the table has a typo.